# Align carousel button to the left and right side of the div container

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-card

As I in the above picture I have used two buttons `left` and `right` button to scroll the images. I want to align the left and right button as shown in below image. Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slidercarousel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.html). Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slidercarousel-yfyemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a few changes, like below :

**scss**

1. Make `.slider-container`'s `position: relative`.
2. Add a child div with class `slides-container` and some padding to accommodate buttons on left/right side.
3. Make `.controls`'s `position: absolute` with `top: 50%`, so that it's always positioned in the vertical middle of `.slider-container` (to make this absolutely positioned, we made `.slider-container` relatively positioned. Because the absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block),  `width: 100%`, so that it takes the full width of `.slider-container` and `justify-content: space-between`, so that both buttons are aligned to the extreme left and right.

```
.slider-container{
    ...
    position: relative;
    .slides-container{
        padding: 0 70px;
    }
    ...
}
...
.controls {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    top: 50%;
}
```

**html**

1. Wrap your `slides` in `slides-container`

```html
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slides-container">
        <div class="slides" #slides>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

I have created a sample at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slidercarousel-9wzhsv).